# Почему в приведённом коде запятая?

Tags: javascript

Разбираю чужой код для исправления ошибки, привожу отрывок. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему после выражений: `S = x.val()`, `e = y()` и `b()` стоят запятые? Для чего они там могут быть нужны?

```
.bind("focus.mask", function() {
  clearTimeout(n);
  var e;
  S = x.val(), e = y(), n = setTimeout(function() {
    b(), e == t.length ? x.caret(0, e) : x.caret(e)
  }, 10)
});
```

Comment: Потому что он минифицированный. Точнее, недоминифицированный: обычно запятые помогают, но тут мешают - можно было 2 символа сэкономить при точках с запятой.

Comment: Вы правы, он был минифицированный, я его распаковал онлайн сервисом. Как я понял здесь запятая выполняет функцию точки с запятой?

Comment: Да. Вместо них можно поставить `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор запятой выполняет каждый из его операндов (слева направо) и возвращает значение последнего операнда.

Вот тут можно посмотреть документацию [Оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Comment: то есть формально в данной конструкции смысла не имеет.

Comment: @teran на мой взгляд тут в ней нет смысла.

Comment: Но ведь здесь значение не возвращается. Можно любую точку с запятой поменять на запятую?

Comment: @L.Culver тут лучше запятые поменять на точку с запятой

Comment: А чем лучше? Наглядностью или функционалом?

Comment: @L.Culver на мой взгляд это понятнее. Так как код пишут для программистов, а не для компьютера.